# In xamarin forms Which override method called in app.cs, when open app from background but app state is killed by OS in background

Tags: xamarin.forms

In xamarin forms application which override method called If we open the app from the background but in the background, the app is loose his state and started from scratch.

Comment: In iOS , when the app entering background , it will be killed after 2 to 3 minutes (unless it contains media player or some other special service). So even if you open it by taping the View , it will still open from launch screen (like click the app icon).

Answer (score 0):

`OnStart` will be called if the app is being started from a killed state

Comment: Thanks for response. my doubt is app is not removed from background but if I open app from background after long time, app opened from scratch insted of previous closing state. In this scenario which override methdo is called.